# Inner product space - proof when u and v are orthogonal

Tags: vectors

prove that if the (u,v)=0 <=> norm(u+v) = norm(u-v)

I can definitely see that it is true if u and v are orthogonal but I am unsure of how to begin this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the norm induced by the inner product. Note that
$$\|u+v\|^2 = (u+v,u+v) = (u,u) + 2(u,v) + (v,v) = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2$$
and
$$\|u-v\|^2 = (u-v,u-v) = (u,u) - 2(u,v) + (v,v) = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2$$

Comment: Never mind I understand now, so this is only true for orthogonal vectors because if (u,v)=0 then the 2(u,v) = 0 which makes them equal. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GGWP Obviously the last equality signs use $(u,v) = 0$ ^^
$$\|f\| = (f,f)^{\frac12}$$

Comment: I understand now, silly me thank you so much!